# Annotations are only available if source level is 5.0 syntax error java

Tags: java, compiler-errors, syntax-error, javac

I am compiling a normal java program with `@Override` annotation(I downloaded a source from internet from some tutorial). Now the `javac` is complaing that

`annotations are only available if source level is 5.0`

Every question on SO or other site relates this to eclipse but I am not using eclipse. I am compiling the code from command line. How can I resolve the problem.

Here is some information that may be useful:

```
$java -version
 java version "1.6.0_13-b03
 (some other not so useful info)
```

Edit:

```
$javac -version
 Eclipse Java Compiler v_677_R32x, 3.2.1 release,....
```

Command for compiling:

```
javac User.java
```

`User.java` is just normal java file. No errors there for sure except this one.

Comment: please provide your whole command line for compiling, and also the output of javac -version

Comment: @radai Please look at the edit. It is using some eclipse compiler. How can I change that

Comment: the java compiler on the path is the eclipse compiler, and not the oracle JDK compiler. looks like youre using eclipse after all :-) please fix your path so that the jdk compiler gets invoked.

Comment: @radai hmm...I figured that out while I was writing edit..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In project properties->Java Build Path/Libraries tab make sure you have JRE System Library 6 ennvironment.

Since you aren't building through eclipse, you will have to use the -source parameter to the compiler to tell it to use a higher language level.  Interestingly it seems the default in the eclipse compiler is not 6 which the oracle compiler uses.

Comment: I do not have a eclipse project for this file. Why do I need to do this

Comment: Ah, I assumed you were using eclipse.  In that case, just use the -source option to specify 5 (or 6), which is what that menu setting does anyway.

Comment: thanks. Can we permanently fix problem(not with alias or something).

Comment: I'm confused that you're using the eclipse compiler but not eclipse.  You could install a full JDK and use it instead.  The properties file which controls the eclipse installation is probably not meant to be manipulated externally.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar problem when deploying a portlet project for Liferay 6.2. The build tool ANT always gave me following Syntax Error:

> Syntax error, annotations are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater

I tried to set the used Java version and so on but all was set up correct. I solved the problem through editing the build.-username-.properties file for the

```
ant deploy
```

command. I just changed the compiler to **modern** and commented the default org.eclipse-compiler out:

```
javac.compiler=modern
#javac.compiler=org.eclipse.jdt.core.JDTCompilerAdapter
```

After that step my project was build and deployed successfully.

Was just searching a while to get that working so I though it maybe would be helpful for someone if I write it down on SO on one of the questions I checked regarding this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Hi resolved the above issue, please follow the steps below:

1. Right click on your project and select `Properties`.
2. Go to the `Java Compiler` and check the enable project specific settings.
3. Set `Jdk` versions according to `jdk` which is installed in your system.
   ex: 1.5, 1.6, 1.7

Answer (score 0):

In command line use -source option of javac command to specify the version. Here is the official documentation of javac:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/javac.html

Comment: Can you tell which version to specify that will not give such errors

Comment: You must specify 1.5 or higher version

Answer (score 0):

Have sorted this legacy issue by the following steps:

1.Go to your project's Properties

2.On the Properties dialog choose the Java Compiler node in the left tree.

3.Finally set the Compiler compliance level to 1.5 or more as that's what for 
  eclipse was crying :-0

4.Rebuild the project