# how to run java awt program written in net beans to linux terminal

Tags: java, linux, netbeans

I have coded for java project using net beans 8.0 ide. code works perfectly on netbeans how ever when i try to run same program on linux terminal it gives me following errors.Can you please help me..!

```
[root@localhost myPackk]# vim WelcomeForm.java
[root@localhost myPackk]# javac WelcomeForm.java
----------
1. WARNING in WelcomeForm.java (at line 12)
        public class WelcomeForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^
The serializable class WelcomeForm does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field of type long
----------
2. ERROR in WelcomeForm.java (at line 26)
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Syntax error, annotations are only available if source level is 5.0
----------
3. ERROR in WelcomeForm.java (at line 26)
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SuppressWarnings cannot be resolved to a type
----------
4. ERROR in WelcomeForm.java (at line 54)
        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
javax.swing.GroupLayout cannot be resolved to a type
----------
5. ERROR in WelcomeForm.java (at line 54)
        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
javax.swing.GroupLayout cannot be resolved to a type
----------
6. ERROR in WelcomeForm.java (at line 57)
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
javax.swing.GroupLayout cannot be resolved
----------
7. ERROR in WelcomeForm.java (at line 58)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
javax.swing.GroupLayout cannot be resolved
----------
8. ERROR in WelcomeForm.java (at line 60)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
javax.swing.GroupLayout cannot be resolved
----------
9. ERROR in WelcomeForm.java (at line 61)
        .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 619, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
javax.swing.GroupLayout cannot be resolved
----------
10. ERROR in WelcomeForm.java (at line 64)
        .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 167, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
javax.swing.GroupLayout cannot be resolved
----------
11. ERROR in WelcomeForm.java (at line 64)
        .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 167, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                                                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
javax.swing.GroupLayout cannot be resolved
----------
12. ERROR in WelcomeForm.java (at line 68)
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
javax.swing.GroupLayout cannot be resolved
----------
13. ERROR in WelcomeForm.java (at line 69)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
javax.swing.GroupLayout cannot be resolved
----------
14. ERROR in WelcomeForm.java (at line 71)
        .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 392, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
javax.swing.GroupLayout cannot be resolved
----------
15. ERROR in WelcomeForm.java (at line 72)
        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
javax.swing.LayoutStyle cannot be resolved
----------
16. ERROR in WelcomeForm.java (at line 73)
        .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 36, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
javax.swing.GroupLayout cannot be resolved
----------
17. ERROR in WelcomeForm.java (at line 73)
        .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 36, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
javax.swing.GroupLayout cannot be resolved
----------
18. ERROR in WelcomeForm.java (at line 77)
        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
javax.swing.GroupLayout cannot be resolved to a type
----------
19. ERROR in WelcomeForm.java (at line 77)
        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
javax.swing.GroupLayout cannot be resolved to a type
----------
20. ERROR in WelcomeForm.java (at line 80)
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
javax.swing.GroupLayout cannot be resolved
----------
21. ERROR in WelcomeForm.java (at line 81)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
javax.swing.GroupLayout cannot be resolved
----------
22. ERROR in WelcomeForm.java (at line 83)
        .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
javax.swing.GroupLayout cannot be resolved
----------
23. ERROR in WelcomeForm.java (at line 83)
        .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
javax.swing.GroupLayout cannot be resolved
----------
24. ERROR in WelcomeForm.java (at line 87)
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
javax.swing.GroupLayout cannot be resolved
----------
25. ERROR in WelcomeForm.java (at line 90)
        .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
javax.swing.GroupLayout cannot be resolved
----------
26. ERROR in WelcomeForm.java (at line 90)
        .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
javax.swing.GroupLayout cannot be resolved
----------
27. ERROR in WelcomeForm.java (at line 90)
        .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                                                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
javax.swing.GroupLayout cannot be resolved
----------
28. ERROR in WelcomeForm.java (at line 91)
        .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
javax.swing.GroupLayout cannot be resolved
----------
29. ERROR in WelcomeForm.java (at line 94)
        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
javax.swing.GroupLayout cannot be resolved to a type
----------
30. ERROR in WelcomeForm.java (at line 94)
        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
javax.swing.GroupLayout cannot be resolved to a type
----------
31. ERROR in WelcomeForm.java (at line 97)
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
javax.swing.GroupLayout cannot be resolved
----------
32. ERROR in WelcomeForm.java (at line 100)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
javax.swing.GroupLayout cannot be resolved
----------
33. ERROR in WelcomeForm.java (at line 100)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
javax.swing.GroupLayout cannot be resolved
----------
34. ERROR in WelcomeForm.java (at line 104)
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
javax.swing.GroupLayout cannot be resolved
----------
35. ERROR in WelcomeForm.java (at line 107)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
javax.swing.GroupLayout cannot be resolved
----------
36. ERROR in WelcomeForm.java (at line 107)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
javax.swing.GroupLayout cannot be resolved
----------
37. ERROR in WelcomeForm.java (at line 107)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                                                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
javax.swing.GroupLayout cannot be resolved
----------
38. ERROR in WelcomeForm.java (at line 108)
        .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
javax.swing.GroupLayout cannot be resolved
----------
39. ERROR in WelcomeForm.java (at line 117)
        new LoginForm().setVisible(true);
            ^^^^^^^^^
LoginForm cannot be resolved to a type
----------
40. ERROR in WelcomeForm.java (at line 130)
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Syntax error, 'for each' statements are only available if source level is 5.0
----------
[root@localhost myPackk]#
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Annotations are only available if source level is 5.0 syntax errror java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18630525/annotations-are-only-available-if-source-level-is-5-0-syntax-errror-java)

Answer (score 0):

Make a `jar` file of your application and run it in terminal with `jar` command.

```
java -jar app.jar
```

Check this [tutorial](http://www.wikihow.com/Generate-JAR-File-in-Netbeans) to generate `jar` file out of your project.