# AspectJ with Web-services and Java 6. How to do?

Tags: java, web-services, aspectj

In my project I want to use a Web-Services with ASpectJ (Aspect-Oriented Programming ). I don't know how to do it.

**HelloWorldService.java :**

```
package WebService;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
eclipseglassfish
@WebService
public class HelloWorldService {
  @WebMethod
  public String  Hellow() {
    String message = "Hi ! i am a simple service....";
    System.out.println("Hi ! i am the a simple service... .");
    return message;   
  } 
}
```

**LogAspectJ.ai :**

```
  public aspect LogAspect { 

    pointcut logHellow() 
    : execution(* WebService.HelloWorldService.Hellow(..));

    before() : logHellow() { 
      System.out.println("AVANT Hellow"); 
    } 

    after() : logHellow() { 
      System.out.println("APRES  Hellow"); 
    } 
}
```

When I do `ajc -d . HelloWorldService.java LogAspect.aj`

I have this error : 
compileAJ:
     [echo] compile iajc
     [iajc] ajc [-d, H:\Workspace ....
    [error] Syntax error, annotations are only available if source level is 5.0
    @WebService
    ^^^^^^^^^^
    [error] Syntax error, annotations are only available if source level is 5.
    0
    @WebMethod
    ^^^^^^^^

Comment: I would start by using either Maven or Gradle to build your project instead of doing it by hand, and also go with Java 8; Java 6 is obsolete.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Annotations are only available if source level is 5.0 syntax errror java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18630525/annotations-are-only-available-if-source-level-is-5-0-syntax-errror-java)

Comment: Try using java 5+ . Check Your project setting and also installed version of java. You can check it by win +d -> cmd -> java -version. After set project to run at least java 5

Comment: I know Java 6 is obsolete but I can use only Java 6. I have that : java version "1.6.0_32"

Comment: no one know the answer ? or something who can help me ?
I have  try to use AspectJ 1.6.11 and aspecJ 1.7.4  ant Ant 1.9.6 and Ant 1.8.4. I have still the same error.

Comment: Maybe you have multiple versions of java on your system and ant is picking up the wrong one.

Comment: Ant use the good one .
When I do this , 
 <target name="print-version"> 
    <echo>Ant Java/JVM version: ${ant.java.version}</echo> 
    <echo>Java/JVM detail version: ${java.version}</echo> 
 </target>

I have this result in the console   :
[echo] Ant Java/JVM version: 1.6
[echo] Java/JVM detail version: 1.6.0_32

Answer (score 0):

In Ant I need to add that : **source="1.6"**
Then I have no error if i do that in Ant :

```
<target name="compileAJ" depends="init"
            description="Compilation avec AspectJ">
        <echo>compile iajc</echo> 
        <iajc srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}" source="1.6"
             classpath="H:\aspectj1.6\lib\aspectjrt.jar"/>
</target>
```